# Помогите составить регулярку, которая ищет совпадения в строках

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, kotlin

Есть 2 строки:

```
val s1 = "м. Петрозаводс"
val s2 = "Петрозаводская"
```

Если написать:

```
s1.toRegex().find(s2 ) // будет null
s2.toRegex().find(s1) // будет null
```

А как должна выглядить regex для находдения части совпадений.

Я ожидаю увидеть результат "Петрозаводс".

Comment: Совсем не должна. Регулярное выражение задает шаблон по которому ищется совпадение в строке. И null выдается совершенно верно так как строки различны. 

Ваша задача звучит по другому: найти максимальную общую подстроку и я сомневаюсь, что ее можно решить регулярным выражением.

Comment: Не пойму немного, откуда взяться `Петрозаодс`, если используется `м. Петрозаодс`? По каким критериям нужна регулярка? Чтобы она отсеивала, то, что до пробела и искала в строке от начала строки `Петрозаодс`? Я не пойму задачу, что необходимо сделать вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun String.hasMatch(other: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): String {
if (this.length > other.length) return other.hasMatch(this, ignoreCase)
var res = ""
for (ai in this.indices) {
    for (len in this.length - ai downTo 0) {
        for (bi in 0 until other.length - len) {
            if (this.regionMatches(ai, other, bi,len, ignoreCase) && len > res.length) {
                res = this.substring(ai, ai + len)
            }
        }
    }
}
return res
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [готовый метод](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_Common_Substring#Kotlin) для нахождения наибольшей общей подстроки:

```
fun lcs(a: String, b: String): String {
    if (a.length > b.length) return lcs(b, a)
    var res = ""
    for (ai in 0 until a.length) {
        for (len in a.length - ai downTo 1) {
            for (bi in 0 until b.length - len) {
                if (a.regionMatches(ai, b, bi,len) && len > res.length) {
                    res = a.substring(ai, ai + len)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Java:

```
static String lcs(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() > b.length())
        return lcs(b, a);

    String res = "";
    for (int ai = 0; ai < a.length(); ai++) {
        for (int len = a.length() - ai; len > 0; len--) {

            for (int bi = 0; bi < b.length() - len; bi++) {

                if (a.regionMatches(ai, b, bi, len) && len > res.length()) {
                    res = a.substring(ai, ai + len);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

См. [пример работы кода в Kotlin](https://rextester.com/VBIV14176):

```
val s1 = "м. Петрозаводс"
val s2 = "Петрозаводская"
println(lcs(s1, s2))
// = Петрозаводс
```

[В Java](https://rextester.com/TRHP9862):

```
String s1 = "м. Петрозаводс";
String  s2 = "Петрозаводская";
System.out.println(lcs(s1, s2));
```